# How can I correctly map an external folder into the Tomcat server.xml file using the context path?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, servlet-container

I am not so into **Tomcat** configuration and I have the following doubts:

The **server.xml** configuration file of my **Tomcat 7** contains this  section:

```
 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true"
        autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">


    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

    <Context path="/my-project/images/" docBase="/data/myproject/cache/images/" />
  </Host>
```

My main doubt is related to this last line:

```
<Context path="/my-project/images/" docBase="/data/myproject/cache/images/" />
```

**/data/myproject/cache/images/** contains some other folder containing images used by my Java EE project.

So what exactly means this line?

I think that it means that it maps the **/my-project/images/** folder to the external folder (external to the project) **/data/myproject/cache/images/**

Is this reasoning correct?

My problem is that my application starts but these images are not shown.

So the exact situation is the following one: these images are not stored directly into the **/data/myproject/cache/images/** external folder but are putted in subdirectoy of this folder, something like this:

```
**/data/myproject/cache/images/subdir1/1.png**
**/data/myproject/cache/images/subdir1/2.png**
**/data/myproject/cache/images/subdir1/3.png**

**/data/myproject/cache/images/subdir2/4.png**
**/data/myproject/cache/images/subdir2/5.png**
**/data/myproject/cache/images/subdir2/6.png**
```

So I think that maybe I have to change this line:

```
<Context path="/my-project/images/" docBase="/data/myproject/cache/images/" />
```

in such a way that if is call something like **/my-project/images/subdir1** it is mapped to **/data/myproject/cache/images/subdir1/**

If it could be my problem (I am absolutly not sure of it), how can I specify this particular behavior?

Answer (score 1):

**path** is the access url of the resource in your project, the **docBase** is the real path of the folder

```
<Context path="/my-project/images/" docBase="/data/myproject/cache/images/" />
```

if your images is in  here : `"/data/myproject/cache/images/subdir1"`
and you want to access these images by url in browser.
try this
1. find the folder in your tomcat.

```
conf/Catalina/localhost
```

2. create a file

```
*.xml
```

3. add these code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Context docBase="/data/myproject/cache/images/subdir1" path="/subdir1" debug="0" reloadable="true" />
```

4. save the image path like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/subdir1/1.png
```

5. restart your tomcat server to enable and load the "*.xml" you have edited.
Try the url in step 4. Can you see the image ? if not, tell me what kind of error do you get. I'll help you figure it out.